# Two queries or one query with a sub-query inside?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on some php code, and i stumbled on something like this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A";
$query2 = "SELECT field_a,field_b FROM TABLE_A";
```

I know these queries are the same as:

```
$query3 = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A), * from TABLE_A";
```

The number of connections being open, or queries being executed would go down. But it would be, performatically speaking, a better solution?

Comment: Benchmark and find out. Unless you discover that it's some kind of performance bottleneck, use the simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use directive SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in first query and function FOUND_ROWS() for second query.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, field_a, field_b FROM TABLE_A;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

if your queries has LIMIT, FOUND_ROWS() anyway return count of all records that match the query criteria

Comment: I'm not sure if [this info is still valid](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) but it may be worth testing if it actually gives better performance.